# using php mail returns error

Tags: php, email

I am using this simple php code

```
mail("myemail@gmail.com", "test", "test" );
```

but when I execute it from console...

```
php test.php
```

it returns this

```
sh: -t: command not found
```

All php is working fine except mail() which returns the error above, which could be the cause ?

I am using this

```
PHP 5.4.23 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Dec 20 2013 10:10:52)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.5.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

Thank you

Comment: Check the sendmail_path variable in your php.ini

Comment: I have this 

sendmail_from no value no value}
sendmail_path  -t -i   -t -i 

Should it be corrected ?

Comment: Yes, something like `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`